# Caption with a line break in Memoir Class

Tags: captions, line-breaking, memoir, subcaption

The following code works with the `report` class.  However, the same code does not work with the `memoir` class. The problem is with the line break in the caption. (FYI: I have TeX Live 2014.)

```
    \documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{memoir}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[domain=0.5:5.5, smooth, variable=\x,black, dotted] plot ({\x},{(\x-3)*(\x-3)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
            }
            \caption{$f(x)=a(x-h)^n$, where $a>0$\\
         and $n$ is even}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
            \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[domain=0.5:5.5, smooth, variable=\x,black, dotted] plot ({\x},{-(\x-3)*(\x-3)});
    \end{tikzpicture}        }
           \caption{$f(x)=a(x-h)^n$, where $a<0$\\
           and $n$ is even}
           \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

How can I get this code to work in `memoir`?

Comment: You missed the closing brace in `\caption{$f(x)=a(x-h)^n$, where $a>0$\\ `

Comment: @Sigur: Nope, it's still complaining. I think, the error lies in the fact, that `\caption` tries to write an explicit linebreak to the LOF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of line-breaks inside `\caption`s are debatable. However, if you need to use them consider the fact that these entries make their way into the List of Figures/Tables. And having line-breaks in those entries may look weird.

1. In order for the `\caption` entries to survive being written to `.lof`/`.lot`, you need to `\protect` certain fragile components. So, use `\protect\\`.
2. Since you don't want line-breaks in the LoF/LoT, also supply an optional argument to the `\caption` that will identify the setting within those lists (even if they're not used).

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption[$f(x)=a(x-h)^n$, where $a>0$ and $n$ is even]
      {$f(x)=a(x-h)^n$, where $a>0$ \protect\\ and $n$ is even}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption[$f(x)=a(x-h)^n$, where $a<0$ and $n$ is even]
      {$f(x)=a(x-h)^n$, where $a<0$ \protect\\ and $n$ is even}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```